# Translate url cakephp

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization

I'm creating a page in CakePHP, i'm trying to translate the url. What i want is to translate the controller name so let says i have this url `domain/da/product` then it should translate it into danish so it became `domain/da/produkt`.

I've written my own url method in AppHelper but i have problems with accessing the model for translation. When i search for accessing model from helper, people are against doing it that way.

So what will be a proper way to do this. When the user use the link i need to make a lookup where i translate it back to `domain/da/product`.

Here is the Apphelper code

```
App::uses('Helper', 'View');
App::import("Model", "ControllerTranslation");

class AppHelper extends Helper {

public function url($url = null, $full = false) {

      $Model = new ControllerTranslation();           
      $lang = Configure::read('Config.language');
      $controller = $Model->find("first",array("conditions"=> array("ControllerTranslation.translation = "=> $url['controller'],"ControllerTranslation.language" => $lang)));
      if (count($controller))
      {
            $url['controller'] = $controller["ControllerTranslation"]["translation"];
      }        
    return parent::url($url, $full);
}
```

Comment: Hi i've updated the question with code, the present code works fine. I've just read that calling a model from a helper class is bad MVC style.

Comment: I have to create a reverse lookup again in the router, is that possible with the __() method?

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the router where i need the non translated value. So in my example it should translate produkt back to product, so it automatically finds the productController

Comment: I think you need to step back and look at the problem you are trying to solve rather than looking at the flaws with the solution you've chosen

Answer (score 0):

if you want the url that has translation = $url['controller'] and language = $lang then you  should use syntax:

```
$controller = $Model->find("first",
  array("conditions"=>   
    array(
           "ControllerTranslation.translation" => $url['controller'],                 
           "ControllerTranslation.language" => $lang
         )
       )
  );
```